# Can amazon ec2 connect to an external oracle database server?

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, oracle11g, external

my project requires me to use PHP and connect to the oracle database service hosted by our department. I want to use amazon ec2 to deploy the project. Is it able to connect to an external oracle database from amazon ec2 by PHP?

I've tried google app engine. It doesn't support external database connection. what a drawback!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it does. By default, Ec2 instances launched in EC2-Classic have full outbound access. So, the Ec2 instance can connect to your Oracle DB Provided your Oracle DB is accessible over the internet (in other words, your Oracle DB has a public IP address and you have firewall rules configured on your end to allow inbound access to Oracle DB).

If you Oracle DB is in a private network, then you need proxy server or SSH tunnel (or something similar) to connect to the instance.

Overall, there is no limitation on EC2 side.

Comment: Hi, Can you give me any documentation link for external database connection?

Comment: There is no special documentation for the same. As you are using PHP on Ec2 instance, refer PHP documentation on how to connect to a Remote Oracle DB. As there are no restrictions from EC2 side, it would be a simple case of PHP connecting to a remote Oracle DB. This would be the same process had you tried to connect a remote oracle DB from PHP code running on your workstation. EC2 is irrelevant in this context. [This](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.oci-connect.php) link might be of your interest.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I do need oci8 module to connect